# How to convert a BigInteger to a scientific notation string and back?

Tags: java, biginteger, notation

I want to convert BigInteger number into a small scientific notation like 1.86e+6 and again reconvert that scientific notation into BigInteger number in Java. Please help.

Comment: Please provide more detail.  What is “small” scientific notation?  Do you want computer-style output like `1.86E+6` or printed book notation like 1.86×10⁶?  Are you familiar with the [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class or do you need that explained?  Showing any attempts at code you’ve written so far would be helpful.

Comment: @Shivansh you need to show what you have already tried so people can help you fix your code.  Please read [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask) and provide an [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `BigDecimal` to parse or output the scientific notation string.

You can can do something like:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1.86E+6");
BigInteger bi = bd.toBigInteger();
```

and reverse:

```
bd = new BigDecimal(bi);
String s = bd.toString();
```

---

#### Update

If you need more user-defined output, then you can use `NumberFormatter`. Don't forget to set the `Locale` to something like `Locale.ROOT`, so you won't get, say a comma as the decimal separator (which is what I got first, in the German locale). Example:

```
    // Create a large, ugly number.
    BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(1001).pow(345);
    
    // Convert to scientific notation using invariant Locale.ROOT
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.######E0", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ROOT));
    String str = formatter.format(bi);
    
    System.out.println(bi);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(str);
    
    // No need for a formatter here.
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(str);
    BigInteger output = bd.toBigInteger();
    
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(output);
```

The output of this is:

```
1411746534642247386926682895653605505594156007645319584856454985824576909030651172402258145880680847831210464829918490010166811079002972726937057623073994129575640372154237767652434547101885830188958723868572869883365738143353635151476880747344348010706072986535185748982964423793694140085891791220972791882178323235649877119554541663599295787824745711388310165587991341807160511741076029768404282877856115942906536866189181255514197337418597936644390730217525723115231014147849887446040444969336884906158293521291748134217314005889949484320602720371789914893639795254884800520873191697159041280591046403928290350948505388703036712226506136642305960716764124836947362932720418554290195995002114233675196543233402547357577387336805972842986766416381431727078044233139876612983206051371851773391882427929601311695575660371227105236375213782469513349953017524299926322617324052803634576283153878896093739315873095260971811967828941219651149370566639839402498088185721432957408746669159107050035686712174548658001777149571278954599340345001

1.411747E1035

1411747000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

*(Yes, BigIntegers can be unwieldy).*

I don't know how big your values are, but the above works well on my Mac. Of course, using scientific notation with only a few decimal digits will lose a lot of precision.

Comment: @Shivansh: Click the upward pointing triangle above the number, left of the answer, to upvote it. You can do that with questions too

Comment: Sir I used NumberFormat formatter=new DecimalFormat("0.######E0);String str=formatter.format(mybiginteger); to convert BigInteger into scientific notation.But when I use very very large numbers then on reconversion of string to BigInteger,after giving some digits it shows only zeros in o/p. Please help.

Comment: @Shivansh: sorry, but I had forgotten about this completely. I updated my answer. Take a look. Could it be that your output contains something else as decimal separator, e.g. `"1,863457E45"` instead of  `"1.863457E45"`? That happened to me before I specified `Locale.Root`.

Comment: This is working fine sir. But is there is any other solution to get exact original number without getting zeros from a very small scientific notation.

Comment: @Shivansh: No, there is not. If you convert to a string with only a few digits, the rest of the digits is lost. Otherwise, if you could retrieve all significant digits from a very short string, you would have found the ultimate compression technique. <g> And there is no need to call me "sir", just say "Rudy".